# CSS: How do I stop hover effects from pushing my text?

Tags: html, css, hover, menu

I hope you understood the question, you can see an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nFbJY/

When you scroll over any of the links they move :(

Any advice on how to solve this issue?

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div.links {float: left; padding-top:15px;}
ul {list-style:none;}
li {float: left; margin: 0 .15em; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC;          border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
a:hover { border: 1px solid blue; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your styling resides on the li, try moving them to the `<a>` tag instead

```
li 
{
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 .15em; 
}

a, a:active, a:visited { 
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}

a:hover 
{ 
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this:

```css
div.links {float: left; padding-top:15px;}
ul {list-style:none;}
li {float: left;}
a {margin: 0 .15em; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
a:hover {border: 1px solid blue; background-color:yellow; }
```

This way you're styling the A tag only instead of both LI and A.  So instead of the effects stacking causing padding/border on 2 elements you're only causing it on one.  Nothing gets pushed around....

Answer (score 1):

Check this one http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/Tn2HV/

```css
div.links {float: left; padding-top:15px;}
ul {list-style:none;}
li { float:left; }
li a { margin: 0 .15em; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; }
li a:hover { background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a `margin` to your `a` elements and add `margin: 0` to `a:hover`. That way, the buttons are always the same width. Or, you can do someting similar with `padding` (or `border`).

EDIT: In your case, use this CSS (esp. the last 2 lines):

```css
div.links {float: left; padding-top:15px;}
ul {list-style:none;}
li {float: left; margin: 0 .15em; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; border: 1px solid #CCC; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;}
a { margin: 0 11px; }
a:hover { border: 1px solid blue; margin: 0; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the CSS definition `a:hover` to `li:hover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/nFbJY/3/

```css
div.links 
{
    float: left; 
    padding-top:15px;
}
ul 
{
    list-style:none;
}
li 
{
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 .15em; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}

li:hover 
{ 
    border: 1px solid blue; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to hover the `li` element instead of `a`

<del>`a:hover { border: 1px solid blue; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; background-color:yellow;}`</del>

```css
li:hover { background-color:yellow; }
```